# Need Help assigning an embedded Object to a parent Object in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am rather new to PowerShell and I'm sure the script gods will have a hay day picking this apart, or reject it out of hand. I have read a lot of documentation regarding creating objects, and assigning members to the objects. A lot of posts are very similar, but I have yet to find one that answers my question directly.

The following is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
$MGSet = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$MgmtSet = New-Object -TypeName Cmdlet.WebService.MgInfo
      $MgmtSet.Param1 = $true
      $MgmtSet.Param2 = $false
      $MgmtSet.oParam = [Cmdlet.WebService.ParamBase] @{
            $PB.differentParam = "Testname"
            $PB.DiffParam2 = $false
            $PB.oDifParamOb = Add-Member -InputObject $MGset - MemberType NoteProperty -Name oDifParamOb -Value ("sys1", "Sys2", "Sys3")
       }
```

First I know this is wrong, but the idea is the Parent object has an object as one of the parameters. Furthermore, the new object also has an embedded object: Parentobject > childobject > baseobject

If I were to execute ...

```
$MgmtSet = New-Object -TypeName Cmdlet.WebService.MgInfo
$MgmtSet
```

I would get

```
ExtensionData                       :
Param1                              : True
Param2                              : False
oParam                              : {Cmdlet.WebService.ParamBase}
```

On the same token if I execute

```
$MgmtSet = New-Object -TypeName Cmdlet.WebService.ParamBase
$MgmtSet
```

I would get

```
ExtensionData                       :
differentParam                      : Testname
DiffParam2                          : False
oDifParamOb                         :
```

The goal is to assign values to the embedded objects and pass it to the parent object. I can use an Array, or a Hash table, but assigning those objects to the parent is where I fall short.

Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both types involved seem to have parameter-less constructors, initializing them via hashtables should work; similarly, custom object `$MGSet` can be created 
inline by casting a hashtable to `[pscustomobject]`:

```
$MgmtSet = [Cmdlet.WebService.MgInfo] @{
   Param1 = $true
   Param2 = $false
   oParam = [Cmdlet.WebService.ParamBase] @{
     differentParam = "Testname"
     DiffParam2 = $false
     oDifParamOb = [pscustomobject] @{ oDifParamOb = "sys1", "Sys2", "Sys3" }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$ParentObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$ChildObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$ChildObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HI" -Value "Spoons are fun"
$ParentObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Sub" -Value $ChildObject

$ParentObject.Sub.HI
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for and gets me closer to my goal. Thank you!